# when rails model is validated using regex for username field it creates conflicts with existing usernames who are already registered

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when i validate username field using regex in rails models everything works locally but it fails in appveyor test for continuous integration my code is conflicting with existing users

currently username accepts any random input my regex pattern ristrict it only to alphabets underscores and spaces but it is failing in appveyor test

my code in users.rb is

```
validates :name, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z_ ]{2,30}\z/,
                         message: ":can contain only alphabets,underscores and spaces" }
```

validates :email, format: { with: /\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9a-z-]+.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\z/ }

what will be possible solution so that i can apply desired validation on username field and also it does not make conflicts with existing users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`on`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on) option for the `validates`, assuming `name` can't be update once created.

```
validates :name, 
          format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z_ ]{2,30}\z/,
          message: ":can contain only alphabets,underscores and spaces" },
          on: :create
```

Comment: still not working can you check  the log file what exactly is wrong 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KRP1OQbMoS1uJ5KlET6YHXbxvTzeNlPL/view?usp=sharing

also here is the link of pull request https://github.com/CircuitVerse/CircuitVerse/pull/1649

Comment: You are getting error when you are trying to create new user. Either your regular expression is not correct or you have to provide valid name in user.rb factory

Comment: thanks sir as tested on local machine everything is working fine so i think regex is correct ..i will need more details on second option as you mentioned how it can be done ?